# Is it correct to say "don't leave active fans or air conditioners directly facing your face when sleeping"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I often have a cold or a sore throat when I sleeps over night with a fan or air conditioner which is on pointing directly to my face.

Is it correct to say "**don't leave active fans or air conditioners directly facing your face when sleeping**"?

I am not sure if "**active fans**" means "**fans that are on or currently running, not in off-state**".

Comment: I would describe the fan as _running_ or _switched on_ rather than _active_.

Comment: I would not use "facing your face", I would use "blowing onto your face" or "blowing air onto your face" or "blowing a draft onto your face". In each the "onto" could be replaced by "at".

Answer (score 1):

'Don't face fans or air-conditioners when sleeping' is more concise.  That the equipment is running is understood.